# Is there a proper subspace of $T$ that includes $T^{n}x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $E$ is a normed space, $T$ is a bounded operator from $E$ to $E$ and $B_E$ is closed unit ball of $E$.

If there is $\exists \epsilon >0$ and $%
\exists y\in B_{E}$ such that $\left\Vert T^{n}x-y\right\Vert >\epsilon $
for all $n\in \mathbb{N} $ and all $x\in B_{E}$ then is there a proper subspace of $T$ include $T^{n}x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Clarification: A proper subspace  means that it is different from $E$ and zero subspace. And, this subspace can be depend on $x$. In fact, is there invariant subspace of $T$ under these conditions?

Comment: Your question is not well formulated. Does $y$ depend on $x$? And what is a proper subspace of $T$? And does this proper subspace depend on $x$?

Comment: y do not depend on x. A proper subspace of T means that it is different from E and zero subspace. And, this subspace can be depend on x. In fact, is there invariant subspace of T under these conditions?